# How to delete multiple rows in ASP.net mvc 4 using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i have code bellow

1.controller action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DeleteSelected(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        var model = new CategoryModel();
        for(var id in ids){
            var res = model.DeleteCategory(id);
            if (res == 1)
            {
               return Json( new
                    {
                        status = true 
                    }
               );  
            }else{
                return Json( new
                    {
                        status = false 
                    }
                );  
            }
        }
    }
```

2.jQuery Event

```
$('a.btn-del-all').off('click').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var boxData = [];
        $("input[name='table_records']:checked").each(function () {
            boxData.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/backend/category/DeleteSelected",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { ids: boxData.join(",") },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.status == true) {
                    alert("Delete Success...");
                } else {
                   alert("Delete Error...");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading data...");
            }
        });
    });
```

3.View

```
<a href="#" class="icon-bar btn-del-all" title="Dell all"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> 
</a>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
     <tr id="item-@item.ID">
     <td class="a-center ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="table_records" value="@item.ID">
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
   </td>
   <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.slug)
   </td>
   <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.parent)
   </td>
   <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lang)
   </td>
    <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ordering)
     </td>
 </tr>
 }
```

And the error i get

> Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebApp.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Comment: paste more of the error

Comment: what is `for(var id in ids){` ?

Comment: Sorry , replace 'ids' to 'table_records', table_records is name of checkbox in view, 'for(var id in table_records)' , in the this line i get more error ':expected'